# Ajax not working sometimes

Tags: ajax

Below is the ajax code. It sometimes works in chrome and sometimes it doesnt. Any ideas?

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST", 
    //prod 
    url: "b2c_process_function.php",
    data: dataString,
    timeout: 4000,
    complete: function() {
        number = (Math.random() + ' ').substring(2,10) + (Math.random() + ' ').substring(2,10);
        window.location.href = 'thankyou.php?OID=' + number + '&from=home'; 
    }
});
```

Comment: It would be a good idea to share the error that you get when it doesn't work.

Comment: Could you give more context to your current problem? e.g whether you are running locally, what error messages do you get

Answer (score 0):

Chnage `data: dataString,` to `data: {dataString:dataString}` as follows:

```
var dataString = 'test'; // or as you like

 $.ajax({
    method: "POST", 
    //prod 
    url: "b2c_process_function.php",
    data: {dataString:dataString},
    timeout: 4000,
    complete: function(data) { //success
        alert(data)
        number = (Math.random() + ' ').substring(2,10) + (Math.random() + ' ').substring(2,10);
        window.location.href = 'thankyou.php?OID=' + number + '&from=home'; 
    }
 });
```